# SSAS Semi-Additive Measures on some dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas

So I'm having trouble trying to configure a new cube that takes a snapshot of my company's open orders each day. Every night, a snapshot is taken and stored in the data warehouse with a date key for the date the snapshot was taken. This date would be the one that we want to be non-additive. However, we also have other dates in this data set, such as scheduled ship-date, order date, etc. that are fully-additive, just like the other non-date dimensions.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can create a cube for this data so that the order totals can be summed across the other dates, but the capture date is LastNonEmpty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first connected Date dimension in the Dimension Usage tab is the semi-additive Date dimension. The rest are additive. I describe the exact behavior [here](https://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2009/2/19/lastnonempty-gotchas).

This answer applies to Multidimensional cubes (not Tabular) which is what I assume you have since you mentioned LastNonEmpty.